# asp:login does not fire any events

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have been searching for a few hours for the solution to this problem.  It seems that many people have similar problems, but none of the solutions work for me.  I need to get the username in order to get the userIndex at log in.

I am using the default login page:

```
%@ Page Title="Log In" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="LunchTogether.Account.Login" %>
<h2>
        Log In
    </h2>
    <p>
        Please enter your username and password.
        <asp:HyperLink ID="RegisterHyperLink" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">Register</asp:HyperLink>
        if you don't have an account.
    </p>
    <asp:Login ID="LoginUser" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" RenderOuterTable="false"         LoggedIn="OnLoggedIn" >
```

The code behind is:

```
  void OnLoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool Authenticated = false;
            Authenticated = SiteSpecificAuthenticationMethod(LoginUser.UserName, LoginUser.Password);
        }
```

I have tried all the events that are listed with the login control and none fire an event.  Is there anything that I am just missing here?

Comment: I think you want to submit the form rather than logged in event.

Comment: The loggedin event would work perfectly, but it is not firing.  Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you have to override the "onLoggedIn" method after creating your own version of the login control.

See this example: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.onloggedin(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.onloggedin%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

I believe you can use some methods like:

```
protected void OnLoginIn(object sender, EventArgs e)

protected void OnLoginError(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

without overriding the control, but I don't think the Context.Profile is set when it goes through them so in your case when you need information about the logged in user I think you will need to override the control.